# Lubuntu 22.04 won't recognize Ralink MT7601U, dmesg reports disagreement re symbol version

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, lubuntu, ralink

Yes, it is yet another Ralink MT7601U question... but the others aren't about my exact situation, so here goes.

Well, I:

- Installed Lubuntu 22.04 (not for myself - I hate systemd with a passion; please get Canonical to drop it; but I digress).
- Stuck the dongle in my USB port.
- See the device with `lsusb` (ID 148f:7601).
- installed a bunch of packages, like `linux-modules` and `linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`. I have the rt2800usb module installed.
- rebooted for good luck

I don't see the interface, e.g. with `ip link show`. And if I try to `modprobe 2800usb`, I get lots of symbol disagreement errors in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
[prefix here] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iterate_interfaces
[prefix here] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iterate_interfaces (err -22)
```

and so on for several dozen symbols.

Why is this happening? Can I solve the problem by identify the offending module and blacklisting it?

Additional info:

Modules I have loaded:

```
crc_itu_t mac80211 cfg80211 tls binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio uvcvideo
snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_memops snd_usb_audio videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common
snd_hda_codec videodev snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_core mc snd_hwdep
snd_pcm joydev input_leds snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event libarc4
snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer mei_pxp mei_hdcp
intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common mei_me snd x86_pkg_temp_thermal mei
intel_powerclamp at24 soundcore coretemp rapl intel_cstate think_lmi
wmi_bmof mac_hid firmware_attributes_class sch_fq_codel iwlwifi_compat
msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport pstore_blk pstore_zone ramoops
reed_solomon efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs
blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq libcrc32c dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log
hid_generic usbhid hid i915 drm_buddy i2c_algo_bit ttm
drm_display_helper cec rc_core crct10dif_pclmul drm_kms_helper
crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel gpio_ich aesni_intel syscopyarea
sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crypto_simd cryptd drm lpc_ich
e1000e ahci i2c_i801 i2c_smbus libahci video wmi
```

Comment: `rt2800usb` is incorrect for your device. How exactly did you install it? Please run: `lsmod` and paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555: Added the list of modules I have loaded. Which module should I be using?

Comment: The module you should *not* be using is iwlwifi_compat. I doubt it will be enough to blacklist it. I recommend that you uninstall the iwlwifi package you installed and reboot. Also, please let us see, in an edit: `modinfo mt7601u | grep alias | grep 7601` and: `sudo dmesg | grep mt76`

Comment: @chili555: This solved it, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to @chili555's for this solution)

- The module for your Ralink WiFi dongle is called `mt7601u`.
- The `mt7601u` module is indeed in conflict with another module you have loaded, `iwlwifi_compat`
- To properly remove `iwlwifi_compat`, don't just blacklist it - remove the relevant package: `apt remove linux-modules-iwlwifi-$(uname-r)`

After you do that, you should see something like this:

```
$ lsmod | grep 7601
mt7601u               147456  0
mac80211             1323008  1 mt7601u
cfg80211             1052672  2 mt7601u,mac80211
$ dmesg | grep 7601
[    2.294967] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    3.476019] random: crng init done
[   14.103065] mt7601u 1-1.6:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[   14.350280] mt7601u 1-1.6:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[   14.750937] mt7601u 1-1.6:1.0: EEPROM ver:0c fae:00
[   14.986105] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
[   15.450532] mt7601u 1-1.6:1.0 wlx200db030b97d: renamed from wlan0
```

... and the interface should now be usable via the panel notification area widget.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working!

Answer (score -1):

Well I have two solutions for you and both of them are **weird** but may helpful

if `lsusb` gives this output

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 22d9:276a OPPO Electronics Corp. RMX2027
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID c0f4:05f5 Usb KeyBoard Usb KeyBoard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:608d Lenovo Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

#### 1. Dual boot with windows 10 (don't know works or not with 11 or 7) :

- First boot with window turn on wifi.
- Restart and boot with linux.
- It just works for me.
- but you need to do it every time you turn your PC on.

It works for me in various distros like mint, mx linux and debian based distros.

#### 2. Install antix linux

- Antix linux uses it's own kernel `4.9.0-326-antix.1-amd64-smp`  (I don't know if it is too old) which includes working driver for `MT7601U` and it is just **plug and play**
  you don't need to do anything for it,
- but you may not like the distro it comes with window managers if you care about it you can install any of your favorite DE.

Comment: Thanks for this, but - two months have passed, and I no longer have the Ralink device nor the machine with Lubuntu 22.04, so I can't check whether this works.